# Select Multiple rows mysqli from different tables to combine and export in CSV

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, mysqli

I have to export a csv file for the orders, but these informations for one order are stored in different tables.. So I have the name of a buyer in a table and what he bought in another table and I have to export in a single row for my csv file..
It's something like this

```
table1: entity_id, billing_name, created_at, grand_total, status 

table2: 
    sku, name, price, base_price, original_price, tax_percent,
    tax_amount, discount_percent, discount_amount, price_incl_tax, order_id

table1.entity_id=table2.order_id (is the way I can GROUP BY)
```

the export part it's clear for me...I just don't knoow how to combine these information to create a row
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you started to write the Query, if so please add that to your question

Comment: It would also be useful to know which columns you want to send to the csv if you want someone to write this for you

Comment: table1.entity_id=table2.order_id is the way you probably have to join the tables. Take a look at JOIN statement on MySQL online guide

Comment: You can either export each row of table2 separately (if you do not want to deal with JSON) or you can combine all corresponding rows from table2 into the single row from table1 (using JSON_ARRAY and JSON_OBJECT functions as described https://scotch.io/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information provided, here is a query that returns the columns mentioned.

You need to `JOIN` the two tables together, you can do this using `JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.order_id = t1.entity_id` where these tables also have an alias of `t1` and `t2`. JOIN info can be seen [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Additionally, it is possible to alias these columns for the purpose of changing the column names for your CSV client using `t1.grand_total AS total`

```
SELECT
  t1.entity_id,
  t1.billing_name,
  t1.created_at,
  t1.grand_total,
  t1.status,
  t2.sku,
  t2.name,
  t2.price,
  t2.base_price,
  t2.original_price,
  t2.tax_percent,
  t2.tax_amount,
  t2.discount_percent,
  t2.discount_amount,
  t2.price_incl_tax,
  t2.order_id
FROM
  table1 t1
  JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.order_id = t1.entity_id
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this way many times, but it did not work....The problem was in the output query and not in the syntax   t2.order_id.. so now it works, thanks

Comment: Do you know how to export these rows with a title too?
Thank you!

Comment: I can try to help. What RDBMS are you using? Do you have any code you've tried?

Comment: Do you want the web server to return a CSV file, or do you want to do this form the CLI?

Comment: I did it:

fp = fopen("lista-ordini.csv","w");
if ($rs = $db->query("SELECT sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id, sales_flat_order_grid.billing_name, sales_flat_order_grid.created_at, , sales_flat_order_grid.grand_total FROM sales_flat_order_grid, sales_flat_order_item WHERE sales_flat_order_grid.entity_id=order_id GROUP BY entity_id"))
{
  while ($row = $rs->fetch_assoc())
  {
    fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
  }
  $rs->close();
}
fclose($fp);
?>
in a php file. Now I would like to have titles in csv columns 
Thanks a lot